# Holding a reference to logger in a static class

Tags: c#, .net, static, global-variables, log4net

I am using log4net in which I am obtaining a reference to the logger within a static class like so:

```
internal static class Constants
{
   public static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
}
```

and using that reference throughout the app like so:

```
Constants.Log.Info(_message);
```

However I've got the feeling that this may cause problems and I realise that constant (global?) variables can be a bad thing.

- Is there anything wrong with this method?
- What are the reasons?
- What can be done to resolve these?

Answer (score 14):

You are correct, that is **not the best approach**, if you want to be able to easily differentiate log levels and use different log targets ("appenders") for each class.

It's usually recommended that each class has a static `ILog` instance, named after it's fully qualified type:

```
namespace Animals
{
   public class Dog
   {
       private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Dog));
   }

   public class Cat
   {
       private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Cat));
   }
}
```

While this looks like more work compared to having a singleton, it proves very handy in the long term. Once you've done this, it is easy to differentiate `Dog` and `Cat` log levels through your configuration file (example shown with [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) syntax):

```
<log4net>

   <!-- appender definitions ommited -->

   <!-- default for all loggers in Animals namespace -->
   <logger name="Animals">
     <level value="WARN"/>
   </logger>

   <!-- ...but we need full debug for Dogs -->
   <logger name="Animals.Dog">
     <level value="DEBUG"/>
   </logger>

   <!-- ...and we want to send Cat messages over e-mail -->
   <logger name="Animals.Cat">
     <level value="INFO"/>
     <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender"/> 
   </logger>

</log4net>
```

Logging frameworks like log4net also use the notion of [hierarchical logging](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=457): a logger is said to be an ancestor of another logger if its name followed by a dot is a prefix of the descendant logger name. To make use of this feature, it's best to avoid naming loggers manually (using hardcoded `string`s), but rather use type information to include the entire namespace.

Comment: I would disagree with this approach.  This requires "plumbing" code in every class which is wasteful and prone to errors.  If your logging solution is well built - it is ok to have a static reference to it.  Many higher end systems are built this way.

Comment: @tsells - I must admit this was my thought when reading this answer, but I was doubting mysef, hence the reason for the question.

Comment: @tsells: well, I am aware of many systems being built exactly the way it's described in my answer (take NHibernate loggers, for example). This *is* the approach recommended by `log4net`, and I fail to see the possible point of failure here ("wasteful and prone to errors"?). It is also the approach which creates least performance impact, because there is less need for runtime logger type resolution (which is needed if there is a single logger), not to mention thread synchronization. If you have a concrete example of a such a "well built logging system", do share it.

Comment: After thinking about this I am going to reverse my original response partially in reference to the static reference.  Going back through the a system I am working on now I see that we implemented a factory pattern to get the logger similar to what log4net suggests.  However - we are doing it in the base classes so the plumbing code doesn't have to exist in every class.  So the code lives in 3 to 4 classes versus hundreds or thousands.....

Answer (score -1):

This essentially creates a singleton, although there are many of problems with that, including making effective unit tests. Unit tests don't need to log and this introduces an unnecessary dependency.

You should consider using an IoC container and dependency injection.

Comment: How is having a dependency on a logging solution interfering with effective unit tests?  I would love to see an example.

Comment: I agree with @tsells: Logging is probably the best exception to the rule of avoiding singletons (although, having a *single* logger is something I don't advocate either). If you are using a logging framework, I highly doubt you ever need to test loggers themselves, or inject logger mocks? And I don't see much harm in having logging enabled for unit tests, logging levels can be configured differently if needed, and it can only help in need of troubleshooting.